# Set a size limit to SAMBA shared directory remotely

Tags: samba, administration, cifs

I have been asked to set up a shared directory for a colleague on a server I manage. I created an account for him on that server, set up a Samba password with *smbpasswd*, created a directory and set it up in the smb.conf file, which I copy below:

```
[global]
workgroup = OURWORKGROUP
server string = Samba Server %v
netbios name = server_i_run
security = user
map to guest = bad user
name resolve order = bcast lmhosts host wins 
dns proxy = no
[coworkerguy]
path = /samba/coworkerguy
valid users = coworkerguy
guest ok = no
writable = yes
browsable = yes
```

Now I have been asked to limit this space to 2Gb. I have looked online for ideas but I can't find anything recent and setting up disk quotas is apparently one of the most popular solutions. I admit I'm not that confident doing that, and furthermore it often comes up that I have to reboot in single user mode - unless I misunderstood something. That is not possible, as I can only ssh remotely to that server. Are there are techniques I could use? If not, could someone point me to an idiot-proof guide?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My solution is not the best, I know, but it works ;-). EDIT: Please read my other answer as well, this answer is an evil hack!

Create a 2Gb file with dd, format the file e.g. ext3, mount it, add it to fstab and use that as a share.

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=filename bs=1024 count=2M
$ sudo mkfs.ext4 filename
$ cat /etc/fstab
/path/to/filename /mount/point ext4 defaults,users
```

Now you point the share to `/mount/point` (or wherever you chose to mount it), so

`path = /samba/coworkerguy` 
becomes
`path = /mount/point`

In UNIX, everything is a file.

Comment: Is that what @umeboshi is suggesting with their suggestion about using LVM? Would it slow things down significantly?

Comment: This answer is similar, but depends on a loopback mounted filesystem.  IOW, you are emulating a block device on the filesystem and forcing the kernel to use two filesystem drivers (or the same one twice) to access a block on the disk.  This would be slower than just using a block device.  LVM is a wonderful tool.  I never fill my drives completely and leave space for things like this that pop up from time to time.  One can always use lvresize later.

Comment: I don't want to leave the impression that serving loopback filesystems over samba is a bad idea.  I do this for windows 7 iso files (https://github.com/umeboshi2/paella/blob/master/vagrant/salt/roots/salt/filesystem-mounts.sls) for automated netboot win7 installs.  However, for writable shares, I feel that going the loopback route is unnecessary unless you don't have lvm or access to the underlying block devices.

Comment: Well, I said it is not the best solution. The problem with LVM on remote servers is that you might need somebody to add a physical device. OP did not mention, but this might be a cloud system - good luck having the provider add a device for you.

Answer (score 4):

There is another, cleaner option. It requires a kernel with disk quotas enabled, but no single user mode.

Basically, you edit your `/etc/fstab` and add `usrquota` to the mount options of the partition. Then you remount the partition:

```
$ sudo mount -o remount /dev/sd<x><y>
```

Where `<x>` is a letter of the disk and `<y>` the partition number on the disk (if you use `uuid`, see `man mount` to mount with `uuid`).

You then issue the following to create a quota file:

```
$ sudo quotacheck -avug
```

Once you have the quota file, it is time to add a quota for `coworkerguy`:

```
$ sudo edquota coworkerguy
```

Note that by default the editor is `vi`, set the `EDITOR` variable to `nano` or `gedit` or whichever editor you fancy and re-run above command.

```
$ export EDITOR=gedit
```

Now you can add `quotacheck` to `cron`

```
$ sudo echo 'quotacheck -avug' >/etc/cron.daily/quotacheck
```

See http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/disk-quota/ for exact steps and output.

Also, see http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialQuotas.html

Comment: Interesting - how can I check if my current kernel has disk quotas enabled? I did not install the system but it's very likely it's one of the stock ones that come with the distribution, not a custom compiled one.

Comment: We can not consider this is a "cleaner" option, because this require to configure the system and not samba itself. I'm also looking for samba-only option.

Comment: Add a feature request to the samba team, I think it is best to use native functionality where possible because it is well tested.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a block device mounted in that directory.  LVM is useful here.  Make a logical volume that is 2G and mount it at `/samba/coworkerguy`.  This will bypass any need for quotas and meet the exact requirements by placing hard restriction on the size.