# Hard inode disk quota not working (via SMB anonymous connection)

Tags: filesystems, samba, quota

So I've decided to share folder via samba without authentication and with limited maximum size.
I've done everything as the second answer from [there](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/182927/set-a-size-limit-to-samba-shared-directory-remotely) said, except that I used journaled quota.
Since anonymous smb connections use `nobody` user, i've set up next quota for it:

```
Disk quotas for user nobody (uid 65534):
Filesystem            blocks       soft       hard     inodes     soft     hard
/dev/sda2                  4          0          6          5        0        1
```

As you see, there are already five inodes instead of one allowed (created empty files via Amaze manager on my android phone) and I can still create more.
`sudo repquota /` output:

```
*** Report for user quotas on device /dev/sda2
Block grace time: 7days; Inode grace time: 7days
                        Block limits                File limits
User            used    soft    hard  grace    used  soft  hard  grace
----------------------------------------------------------------------
root      -- 7719732       0       0         288843     0     0       
man       --    1940       0       0             92     0     0       
nobody    -+       4       0       6              5     0     1  
(and more)
```

I'm using Linux Mint 18.2 with kernel 4.8.0.
What am I doing wrong? Maybe my entire understanding of disk quotas is wrong? Fix me if it is.
(I didn't really try to check block quota, maybe it's working and maybe it's not, I want to deal with inodes first)

Answer (score 1):

`quotaon -av` instead of croning `quotacheck` solved the problem.